# How to find the Gauss sum $\sum_{x=0}^{p-1} e^{2\pi i(ax^2+bx+c)/p}$?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, exponential-sum, gauss-sums

How to find the sum: $\displaystyle \sum_{x=0}^{p-1} e^{2\pi i(ax^2+bx+c)/p}$ where p is prime ?

I'm sure I need to use this:

$\displaystyle \sum_{x=0}^{p-1} e^{2\pi i(x^2)/p}$ = $\sqrt{p}$ when $ p≡3(mod4)$ and $\sqrt{ip}$ when $ p≡1(mod4) $ and maybe I need to complete the square but I don’t know how to get the result

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Let $y=x+u$ where $2au = b\bmod p$ to get the normal Gauss sum up to a constant.

Comment: @reuns thank you I’ll try !